# How not to display MySQL row if the row is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and trying to solve this, went through many articles before asking here but no better answer. I am fetching sql rows using `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

If the rows are empty the frontend displays a empty row which gives a weird look.  There should be some way not to display empty rows from the database.

My code

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
//$timestamp = time();
$day = "" . date("D");
$dayt= "t" . date("D");
$dayr= "r" . date("D");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Time_table WHERE regd='". $_SESSION['TextBox1'] ."'   ORDER BY id DESC");
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='width: 30%'>".$res[$dayt]."</td>";
            echo "<td style='width: 30%'>".$res[$day]."</td>";
            echo "<td style='width: 40%'>".$res[$dayr]."</td>";
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to change your select query to exclude rows with empty column(s).

For example:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Time_table WHERE regd='". $_SESSION['TextBox1'] ."' AND some_possibly_empty_column <> '' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

or if your column allows NULL value, then even better:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Time_table WHERE regd='". $_SESSION['TextBox1'] ."' AND some_possibly_empty_column IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: can i use multiple AND statements for ex : `SELECT * FROM Time_table WHERE regd='". $_SESSION['TextBox1'] ."' AND $day <> '' AND $dayt AND $dayr;` if not how to do it ?

Comment: Yes absolutely. You can like this `AND $day <> '' AND $dayt <> '' AND $dayr <> ''`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check each row according data that can't be empty. Ex:

```
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ( !empty($res[$dayt]) ) {
                echo "<tr>"; 
                echo "<td style='width: 30%'>".$res[$dayt]."</td>";
                echo "<td style='width: 30%'>".$res[$day]."</td>";
                echo "<td style='width: 40%'>".$res[$dayr]."</td>";
            }
        }
```

Don't forget to close your `tr` tag

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\timetable.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for empty values in the where-statement of your SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE xxx != ''
```